# Photoshop Layer Comps are too large

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm making wireframes for a complex dashboard. I have 40+ layer comps and my 10MB photoshop file is turning into a 30MB PDF.  I've already trimmed away unused layers and don't see what else I can do?

I've been doing this for a while and never had a file with such bloat. (Then again this is the first one I'm doing with 47 layer comps.)

Comment: Do you really need the layers inside a pdf file? Probably you can flaten the image before making your pdf.

Comment: I can't flatten it and keep the comps. Each comp uses a different combination of layers. Example: Icon On show a highlight and revealed div.

Answer (score 0):

You might try opening your PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro and then saving it as a Reduced File PDF.

Another thing you can do is export your layer comps as individual PNGs instead of a PDF. They won't be in the same file, but there are ways to then consolidate them in a PDF. If you're on a Mac, [Preview lets you do this really easily](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28795/how-can-i-create-a-multipage-pdf-from-jpgs-in-preview).

Comment: The idea is to quickly show functionality of a dashboard to business users. I ended up breaking it up into separate pdfs but that took some time and the business users didn't like to have to open two different files.